# How to use django template tags in jinja

Tags: django, django-templates, jinja2

Help, please. I have Django project with jinja2 templates. Need to implement Twitter style pagination. I use library - Django EL(Endless) Pagination. How i can use this templatetags in jinja2 template?

```
{% load el_pagination_tags %}
{% paginate entry_list %}
{% for entry in entry_list %}
    {# your code to show the entry #}
{% endfor %}
{% show_more %}
```

Or perhaps there is an easier way to implement this?? Thanks.

Comment: If you want to use Django template tags, why don't you use Django templates rather than Jinja? The syntax is almost the same anyway.

Comment: becouse, I have quite a lot of code with jinja templates

Comment: I don't think that you can mix two template engines. Either you do it with django templates or jinja2 templates. In this case I would advice you to use jinja2 templates and implement the pagination without Django EL.

Comment: thanks, that's exactly what I did.